# Is it possible to assign a hostname as a slave's master in BIND?

Tags: bind, dns-zone, dns-hosting, dyndns

I would like to set up a master and a slave BIND nameserver, where the master is hidden and currently on a dynamic IP. I set up a dynamic DNS service on a separate domain for it.

So far the documentation I've read only shows IP addresses and no host names in the `masters` field of the `zone` section.

Is it possible to use host names there too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, as the syntax requires IP addresses.

Some things to consider:

- How useful it is to have a nameserver with a dynamic IP? That's exactly why there isn't even possibility to use hostnames. Since you can't use this as a listed NS anyway, it's not very useful; you could simply replace it's role as a master with one of the public nameservers.
- If you really need, for some reason, this kind of extra protection for the master nameserver, why does it even have a public IP? You could use a VPN connection between the servers, where the master can have a static private IP. VPN solutions can use hostnames instead of IP addresses.

Comment: Since I would want to set the master as a hidden server, it wouldn't show up in the NS records, actually. The solution with the VPN sounds like a good way around this restriction, I will look into that.